# How to deal with each rows and combined several rows into one row in oracle/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am new to oracle 11g. I've done some research, but none of them does exactly what i want..

Here are my tables.

T1

```
Date_       Name    Subject      Mark
2011        AAA      History      80
2011        AAA      CS           85
2013        AAA      Math         90
2013        AAA      Science      91
2013        AAA      CS           92
```

T2. This is a scale table

```
Subject    Weight
Math         2
CS           2.1
History      1.9
Science      2
```

I want my output to be:

```
T3

Date_    Name   Math   History  CS     Science
2011     AAA            160     178.5
2013     AAA    180             193.2   182
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do a pivot with a multiplication factor.  Here is a method that handles this using explicit aggregation:

```
select Date_, Name,
       sum(case when Subject = 'Math' then T1.Mark * T2.Weight end) as Math,
       sum(case when Subject = 'History' then T1.Mark * T2.Weight end) as History,
       sum(case when Subject = 'CS' then T1.Mark * T2.Weight end) as CS,
       sum(case when Subject = 'Science' then T1.Mark * T2.Weight end) as Science
from T1 join
     T2
     on T1.Subjecct = T2.Subject
group by Date_, Name;
```